# Fixed header & footer with scrollable content

Tags: css, fixed

I set my header and footer to position:fixed. But in case of scrollable content the text goes to the header/footer area: Here's my complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/kaqz1km2/6/

In this case I don't want to use background-image or background-color.

And here's the CSS:

```css
html, body { height:100%; }
header { position:fixed; width:100%; top:0; margin-top:1rem; }
footer { position:fixed; width:100%; bottom:0; line-height:3rem; }
```

Comment: You just need to add a fixed height to your header/footer and set a padding-top/bottom on your body, no 'correct' way to do this.

Comment: Of course it does lol, you also don't wanna set your body height to 100% for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `padding` in `#content`

Also give a background color to `header` and `footer`

Check here the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kaqz1km2/7/)

```
#content { padding: 60px 0 }
```

Comment: I don't want to set background-color because of design issues.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css with

```
html, body { height:auto; }
header { position:fixed; width:100%;top:0;height:50px;line-height:50px; background-color:#fff;}
footer {position:fixed; width:100%; bottom:0; height:50px;line-height:50px;background-color:#fff;}
nav li { display:inline; text-transform:uppercase; } 
p { width:200px; }
li { margin-right:2rem; }
.container{margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;}
```

and add 1 class container to

```
 <pre> <div id="content" class="container"> </pre>
```